# Use Global Scope in Laravel Validation Rule

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In my Laravel 8 project I have an existing **global scope** bound to a model like so:

```php
protected static function booted() {
    static::addGlobalScope(new CompanyScope());
}
```

I already know that you can add a *local scope* to a validation rule like this:

```php
class ExpenseRequest extends FormRequest {
    protected function validationRules(): array {
        return [
            "attachment" => Rule::exists('files')->where(function ($query) {
                (new Expense())->scope($query);
            })
        ];
    }
}
```

I want to add the **global scope** to an "exists" rule, but didn't find anything about how to do this.
Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: Global scope don't apply to rules, as mentioned https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21721

Comment: Yes, I know that the Global scope don't apply automatically to the rules. But I want a way to apply them manually. (So that I don't have to write the exits function multiple times)